# Getting IllegalStateException sometime in Fragment view says view must not be null why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Yes, I have written my view access inside onViewCreated. So sometimes it's showing

`IllegalStateException: view must not be null`

Immediately if I run after cleaning the project, it's working without any error !!!

CONFUSED !

Another confusing issue is if I use view inside onViewCreated

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {myTextView.text = "MyName"}
```

its working fine

but if assign it inside onResponse of a Retrofit call

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    netWorkCallByRetrofit()
} 

netWorkCall(){
   myTextView.text = "MyName"
}
```

it's not working. 
Immediately if I run after cleaning the project, it's working without any error !!! 
Again it's working well if initialize it in onViewCreated
like

```
tv: TextView
tv = myTextView
tv.text = "MyName"
```

it's working!!!

Any clue ?

Comment: Just some guessing here, do you have views in other layout with the same id with myTextView? Change the id might help.

Comment: Yes, I had the same id in other views and renamed as well but the result is same!

Comment: maybe you need to call view.myTextView.text (view - fragment's view)

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment, always make a reference to the view you are returning in `onCreateView`.
I tend to make a `private var thisView: View? = null` in the fragment main body, then in `onCreateView` assign that to the view you are returning. the rest of the fragment always refer to, for example `thisView.myTextView.text` and you shouldn't have any more weird nullpointer errors.
Some code might make this a bit less chaotic:

```
class MyClass: Fragment(){
    private lateinit var thisView: View // can also make it nullable and set it to null here

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_cool_layout, container, false)

        thisView.myTextView.setOnClickListener{
            toast("yaaaay")
        }        
        return thisView
    }
}
```